# JScrollPane for a JPanel inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, layout-manager

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394139/2180785), I came to [using getPreferredSize instead of setPreferredSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi). But I still can't use the `@Override getPreferredSize`, but that's not the main problem I'm facing right now.

I have a `CardLayout` application which calls a class called **HiraganaData**

*HiraganaData* is a class which extends a `JPanel` so it can be used by the `CardLayout`, but it also has 2 more `JPanel`s on it, one for a "back" button and one for the rest of buttons, before using this idea I was using a JTable, but faced problems on making cells as buttons, so I dropped the idea and came with this new one using `GridLayout`. Some of the buttons will be disabled, anyway I can do that and won't include that code since it's not relevant.

So my actual question or problem is:

- How can I add a `JScrollPane` **only** to `buttonsPanel`, did my best
  trying to add it even to the whole "global" pane w/o success.

This is the most aproximate GUI I can do with the same code of my class I just added a JFrame to it.

Not sure if relevant, but I'm using a `CardLayout` with different sizes, in the way @MadProgrammer suggested on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23881790/2180785).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class HiraganaPage extends JPanel {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");
    JButton kanas[][] = new JButton[26][5];
    JButton backButton = new JButton("back");
    JPanel backPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new HiraganaPage();
    }
    
    public HiraganaPage() {
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        backPanel.add(backButton);
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 5));
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        pane.add(backPanel);
        
        //pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                kanas[i][j] = new JButton("1");
                buttonsPanel.add(kanas[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(buttonsPanel);
        pane.add(buttonsPanel);
        this.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(50, 50);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
    }
}
```

This is how it looks like in my complete application

[image]

And this is how it looks like in the MCVE.

[image]

Comment: The short answer is, don't screw with the preferred size of the panel...

Comment: @MadProgrammer you mean `pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));` that line? commented ok, looks better but scroll doesn't appear that way either.

Comment: Check answer, you're not actually adding anything to the scroll pane nor are you adding the scroll pane to anything...By convention, you should always avoid using `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` as it will cause more problems than it will solve, instead, override the appropriate method instead ... as required ...

Comment: MCVE, clear problem description, evidence of research, two pertinent screenshots. +1(thousand).  Great question.

Comment: Oh thanks @AndrewThompson, there are some people I see in here on SO like you, MadProgrammer, Kleopatra, thrashgod and a couple of more people that I would love to become as good as you, I always see answers from all of you and make me show more effort on each Q & A I write.

Comment: Glad to see that your efforts paid off in a swift answer from @MadProgrammer.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem you've facing is the fact that you removing the `buttonsPane` from the scroll pane when you add it to the `pane`...

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(buttonsPanel);
pane.add(buttonsPanel);
this.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

And the fact that you never actually add the scroll pane to anything doesn't help either.

A component may only have a single parent, so when you add `buttonsPane` to `pane`, it is effectively removed from the scroll pane

Instead, set the layout manager of the `HiraganaPage` to `BorderLayout`, add the `buttonsPanel` to the scroll pane and add the scroll pane to the `CENTER` position of the `HiraganaPage` then add the `pane` to the `NORTH` position of the `HiraganaPage`

[image: Buttons]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestScrollPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestScrollPane();
    }

    public TestScrollPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new HiraganaPage());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class HiraganaPage extends JPanel {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");
        JButton kanas[][] = new JButton[26][5];
        JButton backButton = new JButton("back");
        JPanel backPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();

        public HiraganaPage() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel pane = new JPanel();
            backPanel.add(backButton);
            buttonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 5));
            pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            pane.add(backPanel);

//            pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    kanas[i][j] = new JButton("1");
                    buttonsPanel.add(kanas[i][j]);
                }
            }

            add(pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(new JScrollPane(buttonsPanel));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah I noticed that part of the scroll while I was editing post too... but the part on the parents is interesting... and now I see how you use the `@Override` part too I was doing it in a wrong way (inside the constructor instead of as a method). Let me analize it a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple but even by doing the MCVE didn't noticed about the add of scroll. You solved more than one of my questions by this :)