# How to add gaps between components in Jscrollpane?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jscrollpane

I am using JScrollpane and adding buttons on it dynamically. JScrollpane does **not allow use of layouts.** I want to increase space vertically and horizontally between buttons.

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Comment: Insert a panel in between the scrollpane and the buttons, i.e. add the buttons to the panel and the panel to the scrollpane.

Comment: Create a panel, add you components to this panel, using what ever layout you want.  Set this panel as the scroll panels `viewport view`

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987832/jscrollpane-for-a-jpanel-inside-a-jpanel/24987880#24987880)

Comment: _adding buttons on it dynamically_ how do you add multiple buttons to the JScrollpane ?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. It is easy and useful method.

Answer (score 1):

Add `JPanel` to your `JScrollPane`, and change the layout of the `JPanel`.
After that, you can build all your gui inside your `JPanel` without the limitation of `JScrollPane`.